# Method to assign incremental line # values to records via Process Builder Insert process?

Tags: process-builder

I have a requirement when an new Order Item record is created to assign a line# value based on the last assigned line# for the parent Order.    I have a roll-up summary field on the Order object that holds the highest currently assigned line # value (number field on Order Items).  I am still somewhat new to Process Builder/Flows.   I tried to assign the value in PB but as expected this only works if 1 line is inserted otherwise all inserted lines get the same value.   I then tried doing this from flow called by the process and the flow seemed to assign the numbers (as seen in debug log) however the values did not stick - my thought here is that since the records do not have Id value yet Flow changes to fields does not stick when the Flow finishes the the process builder process continues.

Any tips on how to do this - I'm think I may have to write a trigger on Order Item object but trying to do this project without any Apex if possible.

Comment: The flow should be the correct method, but I believe you have to explicitly save the records using a Record Update panel in the flow. Did you try that?

Comment: A flow would certainly do this with a loop element and a variable getting incremented then having an Create record for the order item object.

Comment: Yes I did try an fast update in the Flow.  Looking at the debug log the flow is assigning the desired values to the field but after the flow ends and goes back to my process builder process the final result is the field is empty.